# PHP In Array Exceptions

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm having some issues with `in_array` function in php, i have a reset function which needs a `$key` variable, what i'm facing is, `in_array` is not accepting if the `uri_string` is admin/user/reset, and i got redirected to login page, but if i modify the code below to exact password reset key like admin/user/reset/PasswordResetKey, it doesn't redirect as you can guess.

As i've seen from php manual, isn't it enough that string to just contain the reset in `uri_string` or i'm wrong?

```
$exceptions = array('admin/user/login', 'admin/user/forgot', 'admin/user/logout', 'admin/user/reset');
if(in_array(uri_string(),$exceptions) == FALSE){
if($this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE){
  redirect('admin/user/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could **[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** the `uri_string` variable to create an array of segments, and then pass the third segment for the `in_array` check. Then your exceptions can just be `array('login', 'logout', 'reset', 'forgot');`

```
$exceptions = array('login', 'forgot', 'logout', 'reset');
uri = explode('/', uri_string());
if(in_array(uri[2],$exceptions) == FALSE){
if($this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE){
  redirect('admin/user/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` compares literal values passed in to literal values in your matches array, it won't do partial strings. What you can do is this:

```
$exceptions = array('admin/user/login', 'admin/user/forgot', 'admin/user/logout', 'admin/user/reset');
foreach($exceptions as $exception) {
    if(strpos(uri_string(), $exception === false) {
        if($this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE){
            redirect('admin/user/login');
        }
    }
}
// no exceptions caught if you get to here
```

You may want to use `stripos` instead (case insensitive): http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: sorry for late response but it doesn't come to the redirect, prevents the loggedin check.